# Eclipse canonical list of command line options

Tags: java, eclipse

I have googled all the obvious strings, searched through FAQs but cannot find a canonical list of command line options for eclipse.

I have installed eclipse on an NFS mounted directory and upon upgrading to `helios` immediately began having errors with lock files.

The NFS export options are (rw,insecure,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)
I can't process locks in the workspace (an NFS dir) nor in
eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/

Upon starting eclipse, eclipse posts a dialog

`Locking is not possible in the directory "(NFS path)/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi". A common reason is that the file system or Runtime Environment does not support file locking for that location. Please choose a different location, or disable file locking passing "-Dosgi.locking=none" as a VM argument.`

Starting eclipse directly with the arg `-Dosgi.locking=none`
still belches same error. Since it's a VM arg, I cannot figure out how/where to specify an alternate lock dir or none; as stated, I can't even find a canonical list of all eclipse args.

Thanks,
bsd

64bit Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
AMD Phenom II X4 940 (Black) 
8GB DDR2 4x2GB unganged
ASUS M4A785-M

Answer (score 7):

Try the *Eclipse runtime options* page on the Eclipse site:

- [Eclipse Galileo](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)
- [Eclipse Indigo](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)
- [Eclipse Juno](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html)

If at all possible, arrange that both your Eclipse installation *and* your Eclipse workspaces are on a local disc drive.  You will notice the difference in performance versus NFS.

Comment: Agree, Eclipse uses MANY files all the time (which can be evidenced by the hardworking anti-virus programs under Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any command line options when starting eclipse. For some reason, it appears that if there are any command line options, that the default eclipse.ini configuration file is not used.

I think that you also need to add the "-Dosgi.locking=none" AFTER a -vmargs parameter.

This may be helpful, but the information is a little outdated...
http://www.mhworth.com/pub/blogs/matt/?p=11