# Cannot launch multiple instances of Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I have multiple Eclipse versions installed in different locations (F:/eclipse-indigo, F:/eclipse-ganymede, F:/eclipse-juno). Indigo and ganymede allow me to launch multiple instances as long as I choose a different workspace. When launching a second instance of Juno I get the error stating "Java was started but returned exit code=1".

[image: Juno Error]

I've search for the error but most solutions were for OP not being able to launch Juno at all.

I can launch one instance fine but the second instance doesn't even allow me to choose a different workspace. 
Just the error message above.

Comment: Could you edit your question, so that the error log is in a text box (code), and not a screenshot? Are there any additional plugins installed, or is that a Juno vanilla installation?

Comment: mliebelt, I would be happy to if the Eclipse developers would make the text selectable. Otherwise I would have to type it all.

Comment: If you go to the directory `eclipse/.metadata/` you should find there the file `.log` that should have that error message as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this order:

- Update your Java installation to a recent version. There are bugs in older Java versions causing similar problems: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7002666
- Explicitly set the -vm argument in eclipse.ini to point to the Java installation that you want to use (in case there are multiple). Your Eclipse installation currently uses whatever Java was last installed (as that one copied itself into the system32 folder, from where it is started according to the error message).
- Compare the eclipse.ini of Juno and one other version. Ignore the DLL and file names, but look if you changed some of the vm options (like memory size) in your old installation. If so, copy those settings into your Juno eclipse.ini.

Comment: Bananeweizen, thanks for the tip. I compared the ini files and noticed the jmx settings in juno's ini file. Then it dawned on me, each time I tried to launch juno the jmx ports would conflict. Took the jmx settings out and now I can launch multiple instances with different workspace. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start Juno explicitly by giving the workspace as argument like in the following shortcut:

> F:\eclipse-juno\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data F:\eclipse-juno\ws1

If that does work, there is something wrong (in Juno) with selecting the workspace at the beginning. I try all the time to be explicit with which workspace I want to run Eclipse by creating a batch file or shortcut command like the above.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814086/eclipse-canonical-list-of-command-line-options) for typical command line options.

Comment: mliedelt, thanks for the suggestion. I created a shortcut like you mentioned using the -data option. It works fine if there isn't another Juno instance running. If another instance is running I get the same error.